# Access dictionary value when the key is a tuple

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to Python and I have a problem where I need to get the value from a dictionary where the keys are tuples. For example:

```
ones = {(1,2,6,10):3, (4,5,9):4, (3,7,8):5}
```

I know that each number appears ones in the keys, and I want to access the value where the key has the number 2 in (the value will be 3).

Can I get any help on how to access this value?

Comment: A dictionary should contain the keys you intend to access it with.

Answer (score 3):

You could "flatten" the dictionary using the following comprehension:

```
ones = {(1,2,6,10):3, (4,5,9):4, (3,7,8):5}

flat = {element: value for key, value in ones.items() for element in key}
```

Now you can get the value of any key from the tuples via `flat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate **ones** and check if 2 is present in the key

```
In [24]: ones = {(1,2,6,10):3, (4,5,9):4, (3,7,8):5}

In [25]: for k, v in ones.iteritems():
   ....:     if 2 in k:
   ....:         print v
   ....:         
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the normal dictionary access when you are looking for *one subelement* of a key. You'll have to loop:

```
value_for_2 = next(ones[key] for key in ones if 2 in key)
```

would find the first match (where 'first' is arbitrary, as dictionaries are not ordered).

If your tuple elements really are unique, *and* you need to do multiple look-ups, then convert your dictionary first to use the tuple elements as keys instead:

```
converted = {t_elem: value for key in ones for t_elem in key}
```

Don't worry about the value duplication here. Values don't need to be unique, and all you do is store *references*; the above won't create copies of the values.

Now you can use fast key lookups again:

```
value_for_2 = converted[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ones = {(1,2,6,10):3, (4,5,9):4, (3,7,8):5}
for key, value in ones.items():
    if 2 in key:
        print(value)
```

out:

```
3
```